# Asp.net MVC4, defaultRedirect is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/HttpError"> // is not working
    <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/Error/HttpError" statusCode="500" /> // also it is not working
</customErrors>
```

Error Controller

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Error/

    public ActionResult HttpError()
    {
        return Content("HttpError was called!");
        //return View("Error");
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound(string aspxerrorpath)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

For the 404 error, it call NotFound action as well, but for the other errors, it never hit the HttpError method.

```
public ActionResult ETest()
{
    throw new Exception("yahoo");
}
```

I run the above test code, it directly goes Error.cshtml page.

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this in your FilterConfigs.cs?

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

The HandleError attribute is necessary to handle default errors.

Comment: Yes, I have. but HttpError is never called.

Comment: @Expertwannabe - you are doing a remote connection, correct?  You do not see the error handler when calling it on your local machine.

Comment: @ thank you for your concern, I tried on local machine but it wasn't work. And I could solve this using Application_error instead of CustomErrors.